# Database Design For reporting comparison results

Tags: sql-server, database-design, powerbi

We are going to design an table architecture. Here I wanted to compare same kind of data coming from different sources say `Source_A` and `Source_B`. I have to compare few attributes and identify below cases

1. Mismatches in attribute1
2. Mismatches in attribute2
3. Data that are missing in source_A
4. Data that are missing in Source_B.

Finally i have report to the same in PowerBI with charts. For now I have 2 tables `A_DATA` and `B_DATA` to store the incoming data and both are having below structure (this is just a sample, I have lot more columns)

```
+---------------+
| Columns       |
+---------------+
| Material_ID   |
+---------------+
| Material_Name |
+---------------+
| Material_Type |
+---------------+
| Quantity      |
+---------------+
```

Now I'm confused whether should I create separate table for 4 cases(Mismatch,Source_A missing,Source_B Missing) or In single table I should have one more column saying `Status` and keep everything there. For reporting in PowerBI (like out of 1K rows, 5K are mismatches). Please suggest which one is better for reporting cases. Im really confused.

Comment: I'm confused too! How about adding some sample data and expected results to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say neither of your two options (additional column, or new table) are optimal. I think this would be best handled with a view. Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW MisMatches
AS
SELECT  Material_ID = ISNULL(a.Material_ID, b.Material_ID),
        Status = CASE WHEN a.Material_ID IS NULL THEN 'Mising A'
                      WHEN b.Material_ID IS NULL THEN 'Mising B'
                      WHEN a.Material_Name <> b.Material_Name THEN 'Mismatch Name'
                      WHEN a.Material_Type <> b.Material_Type THEN 'Mismatch Type'
                      WHEN a.Quantity <> b.Quantity THEN 'Mismatch Quantity'
                    END,
        MaterialName_A = a.Material_Name,
        MaterialName_B = b.Material_Name,
        Material_Type_A = a.Material_Type,
        Material_Type_B = b.Material_Type,
        Quantity_A = a.Quantity,
        Quantity_B = b.Quantity
FROM    A_Data AS a
        FULL JOIN B_Data AS b
            ON b.Material_ID = a.Material_ID
WHERE   CHECKSUM(a.Material_Name, a.Material_Type, a.Quantity) <> CHECKSUM(b.Material_Name, b.Material_Type, b.Quantity);
```

This short circuits on your status column which may not be what you want, that is to say that if you name, quantity and type all don't match, then the status will only tell you that the name is a mismatch. If you want all mis-matches you will need to extend the case expression slightly. Also, if any of your columns are nullable, you will need to handle this in the `Status` case expression, e.g.

```
WHEN a.Quantity <> b.Quantity OR a.Quantity IS NULL OR b.Quantity IS NULL THEN ...
```

I have also had to make an assumption about how you identify a match, but hopefully this gives the general gist of it

**Edit**

There is a better way of doing this rather than `CHECKSUM`:

```
CREATE VIEW MisMatches
AS
SELECT  Material_ID = ISNULL(a.Material_ID, b.Material_ID),
        Status = CASE WHEN a.Material_ID IS NULL THEN 'Mising A'
                      WHEN b.Material_ID IS NULL THEN 'Mising B'
                      WHEN a.Material_Name <> b.Material_Name THEN 'Mismatch Name'
                      WHEN a.Material_Type <> b.Material_Type THEN 'Mismatch Type'
                      WHEN a.Quantity <> b.Quantity THEN 'Mismatch Quantity'
                    END,
        MaterialName_A = a.Material_Name,
        MaterialName_B = b.Material_Name,
        Material_Type_A = a.Material_Type,
        Material_Type_B = b.Material_Type,
        Quantity_A = a.Quantity,
        Quantity_B = b.Quantity
FROM    A_Data AS a
        FULL JOIN B_Data AS b
            ON b.Material_ID = a.Material_ID
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  a.Material_Name, a.Material_Type, a.Quantity
            INTERSECT 
            SELECT  b.Material_Name, b.Material_Type, b.Quantity
        );
```

I discovered this read the following article: [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot @GarethD. This gives a great insight. I have 2 clarifications 1) what is the use of that `checksum` 2) Can i import this view in PowerBI and create charts? Im actually planning to build SSAS tabular model and take data from there to create reports in PoweBI.

Comment: 1. [`CHECKSUM()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) just determines if the values are different. If the 3 attributes are the same in both tables, then the result of `CHECKSUM` will be the same, and the records will be excluded from the view. It is basically shorthand for (`Name <> Name OR Type <> Type OR Quantity <> Quantity`), however, it also matches `NULL` whereas a simple equality check will require explicit checks to see if the value in both tables is `NULL`

Comment: 2. Yes, you can use a view in exactly the same way as a table. The benefit of a view is, as it is simply a stored query, when the underlying data changes, the result of the view changes, whereas if you store it in a 3rd table, you need to remember to update this table every time your data in your other two tables changes.

Comment: No problem. Stackoverflow doesn't half confuse me sometimes. I don't understand how a question can be closed as "Lacks details or clarity" an hour and half **after** an answer has been accepted. If someone was able to answer it, and the answer did in fact answer the question, then it clearly isn't that lacking in details or clarity....

Comment: True!! :( Can i raise this concern somewhere? I'm not sure why it was closed.

Comment: I wouldn't bother raising it as a concern, ultimately there is no harm done. The requirements were  not crystal clear in the question, so I can understand the close votes that were cast before an answer was accepted, just not the one after it.